# Add object with MediaPlayer get in OnCompletionListener

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How to set an object with media player . That object I want to get in  `OnCompletionListener`

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
       //mp.set("data"); // i wonna put string data
        mp.setDataSource(sound);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(completelistner);
        OnCompletionListener completelistner = new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         //mp.get("data");

    }
};
```

Comment: Which object? If you want `MediaPlayer` object then you need to make it global.

Comment: ya that is global but how i can add data with mp object

Answer (score 1):

Make it like this:

```
public class YourClass {

private MediaPlayr mp; // now it is a global variable


mp = new MediaPlayer();


}
```

Edit: according to [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), MediaPlayer (mp) hasn't got any mp.set(String) or mp.get(String) methods.

Comment: ya but how i can add data with that one mp.set ("anystring"); like and get in listner

Comment: ya that has not but any method like this

Comment: Now I don't know what you actually need.